# How can I automatically put a container on AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, pipeline, amazon-ecs

I currently use the following procedure to put a docker container to ECS:

1. Execute `aws ecr get-login --profile tutorial`
2. Paste the returned stuff in the following shell script

The shell script which creates the container

```
# Returned by the command in (1)
sudo docker login -u AWS -p looooong -e none https://foobar.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

# Remaining steps
sudo service docker restart

sudo docker build  -t ${image} .
sudo docker tag ${image} ${fullname}

sudo docker push ${fullname}
```

My question:

Currently, I just the `sudo docker login ...` line every time manually. Can I somehow execute `aws ecr get-login --profile tutorial` and execute the returned command (with sudo) automatically?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using sudo to run docker?

Comment: @cricket_007 -- isn't this pretty common throughout the industry, mainly due to the difficulty in setting up docker for use without root? [related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo)

Comment: @MrDuk most installs I have done add the running user to a docker group, which sure is equivalent to root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You may use the [eval](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/eval.htm) to execute docker login command.

For Example:

```
eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)
```

Sample Shell script in your case would be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)
# Remaining steps
sudo service docker restart

sudo docker build  -t ${image} .
sudo docker tag ${image} ${fullname}

sudo docker push ${fullname}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write string bash command suround with back quote to execute it.

```
`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2`
```